# Motorcycle physics question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws

Does the combined center of gravity of the system change when I move horizontally on the motorcycle? Or does the bike compensate completaly by tilting to the other side, producing no net force?

Comment: It's complicated. http://www.cornell.edu/video/andy-ruina-explains-how-bicycles-balance-themselves

Answer (score 0):

If you and your motorcycle were isolated, then that would be true according to conservation of momentum. However, there is friction between the tyres of the motorcycle and the road, so this reasoning isn't true. In fact, it depends on the characteristics of the motorcycle.

Comment: Why did people put me on hold? What is unclear?